# add git package to existing xcode project

Tags: xcode, git, github, xcode7

How do you use a git package (I am strugling with [this](https://github.com/Daniel1of1/CSwiftV) one, but any other will probably cause problems too) in already existing OSX Project? Sorry if this is a newbie question. Never used source control before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Git [Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to add this repo as a submodule. Or use a system like [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org) to manage dependencies.